# How to fetch specified element from Stack implemented in ArrayList by using only primitives

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist, primitive

I have a situation where Stack data structure is implemented using ArrayList in Java and have to make use of a method which has to use only primitives and return the corresponding element specified through the index.

The code is mentioned below:

```
public class StackTest {
    public static void main(String... s) throws Exception {
        MyStack stack = new MyStack();
        int random = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        stack.push(10);
        stack.push(20);
        stack.push(30);
        stack.push(random);
        stack.push(50);
        stack.push(60);

        assertTrue(getStackElement(stack, 0) == 60);
        assertTrue(getStackElement(stack, 1) == 50);
        assertTrue(getStackElement(stack, 3) == 30);
        assertTrue(getStackElement(stack, 4) == 20);
        assertTrue(getStackElement(stack, 5) == 10);
        try {
            getStackElement(stack, 6);
            assertTrue(false);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            assertTrue(true);
        }
        assertTrue(getStackElement(stack, 2) == random);
    }
    public static void assertTrue(boolean v) {
        if(!v) {
            Thread.dumpStack();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static int getStackElement(MyStack stack, int index) throws Exception
    {
        // 1) I CAN ONLY WRITE CODE HERE
        // 2) DO NOT MODIFY ANYTHING ELSE
        // 3) USE OF new KEYWORD IS NOT ALLOWED
        // 4) DO NOT USE REFLECTION
        // 5) DO NOT USE STRING CONCATENATION

    }

}
class MyStack {
    private java.util.List<Integer> list;
    public MyStack() {
        list = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
    public int pop() {
        if(isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Stack is empty!");
        return list.remove(list.size() - 1);
    }
    public void push(int i) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    public int peek() {
        if(isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Stack is empty!");
        return list.get(list.size() - 1);
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return list.size() == 0;
    }
}
```

*

The following rules have to be followed:

• If the index is out of range, an Exception must be thrown (any Exception will do) but you can assume that no negative index will be passed in

• The stack object passed into the method must remain unmodified upon return (even if an Exception was thrown)

• Do not create any other objects in the method, including Strings, arrays; use only primitive types

• Do not define any other classes and methods

• Do not use reflection

• Do not modify the MyStack class

Please find my code below:

```
public static int getStackElement(MyStack stack, int index) throws Exception
    {
        int returnCode = 0;
        int count = 0;

        int first=0,second=0,third=0,fourth=0,fifth=0,sixth=0;

        /* Counting & Fetching the elements from Stack  START */

        if(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            count++;
            sixth = stack.pop();
        }
        if(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            count++;
            fifth = stack.pop();
        }
        if(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            count++;
            fourth = stack.pop();
        }
        if(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            count++;
            third = stack.pop();
        }
        if(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            count++;
            second = stack.pop();
        }
        if(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            count++;
            first = stack.pop();
        }
        /* Counting & Fetching the elements from Stack  END */

        /*  Inserting elements into Stack   START   */
        if(count == 1)
        {
            stack.push(sixth);
        }
        else if(count == 2)
        {
            stack.push(fifth);
            stack.push(sixth);
        }
        else if(count == 3)
        {
            stack.push(fourth);
            stack.push(fifth);
            stack.push(sixth);
        }
        else if(count == 4)
        {
            stack.push(third);
            stack.push(fourth);
            stack.push(fifth);
            stack.push(sixth);
        }
        else if(count == 5)
        {
            stack.push(second);
            stack.push(third);
            stack.push(fourth);
            stack.push(fifth);
            stack.push(sixth);
        }
        else if(count == 6)
        {
            stack.push(first);
            stack.push(second);
            stack.push(third);
            stack.push(fourth);
            stack.push(fifth);
            stack.push(sixth);
        }
        /*  Inserting elements into Stack   END */

        if(index >= count)
        {
            System.out.println("Throwing Exception");
            throw new Exception("Index out of range");
        }

        if(index == 0)
            returnCode = sixth;
        else if(index == 1)
            returnCode = fifth;
        else if(index == 2)
            returnCode = fourth;
        else if(index == 3)
            returnCode = third;
        else if(index == 4)
            returnCode = second;
        else if(index == 5)
            returnCode = first;

        return returnCode;
    }
```

This solution is not efficient and I am looking for better solution than this.

Thanks,

Comment: Okay, so that's the problem statement - which I assume is your homework. So, what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet... Sorry for late reply, I did not see your comment. I have edited the question and pasted my code in it.

Comment: What are the primitives? Can you use only push and pop? Can you not use a loop?

Comment: Hi @JustinKaeser .. It means only primitive types can be used like int, char, boolean, double, long, etc.
We can use push(), pop(), peek(), isEmpty() along with loops as well.